# How to Fill a cursor in a for loop with sqlite query

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm trying to fill a cursor in a for loop, in loop each time query executes returns a row and cursor fill with that row but each time a new row overwrites in cursor and All2 count is
always 1. I want each time query executes add a new record to All2 and not overwrite on the previous one.

```
Random randomGenerator = new Random();
int[] randomIntNumbers = new int[12];
for (int i = 1; i <= 11; ++i){

    int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(12);                    
    randomIntNumbers[i] = randomInt;    

}


for(int i=0;i<11;i++){

    All2 = mDB.query(DatabaseOpenHelper.TABLE_NAME,
            DatabaseOpenHelper.columns, "L=?", new String[]{""randomIntNumbers[i]}, 
            null, null,null);   

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

`query` returns a new cursor object.

To get multiple rows, you have to query them at once:

```
All2 = mDB.query(DatabaseOpenHelper.TABLE_NAME,
                 DatabaseOpenHelper.columns,
                 "L IN (... all the numbers ...)",
                 null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: What if do not know the numbers? or there are dozens of them? I updated the Question.